# Swift: Nested type erasure

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, type-erasure

Using Swift 3.0 (I could use Swift 4.0 if that would help me... But I don't think it will) I would like to Type Erase two levels. I what to type erase a protocol having an associatedtype, which conforms to a protocol that in turn itself has an associatedtype. So one could say that I want to type erase *nested* associatedtypes.

The code below is an extremely simplified version of my code, but it is more clear that way. So what I really want is something like this:

## Original Scenario - Unsolved

```
protocol Motor {
    var power: Int { get } 
}

protocol Vehicle {
    associatedType Engine: Motor
    var engine: Engine { get }
}

protocol Transportation {
    associatedType Transport: Vehicle
    var transport: Transport { get }
}
```

And then I would like to type erase `Transportation` and be able to store an array of `AnyTransportation` which could have any `Vehicle` which in turn could have any `Motor`.

So this is a scenario with 3 protocols, where 2 of them have (*nested*) associatedtypes.

I do not know how to do this. Actually, I do not even know how to solve the even more simple scenario:

## Simplified Scenario - Unsolved

We could simplify the original scenario above to a version where we have 2 protocols, where only 1 of them have an associatedtype:

```
protocol Vehicle {
    var speed: Int { get }
}

protocol Transportation {
    associatedtype Transport: Vehicle
    var transport: Transport { get }
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Then lets say that we have a `Bus` conforming to `Vehicle`:

```
struct Bus: Vehicle {
    var speed: Int { return 60 }
}
```

And then we have two different *BusLines*, `RedBusLine` and `BlueBusLine` both conforming to `Transportation`

```
struct RedBusLine: Transportation {
    let transport: Bus
    var name = "Red line"
    init(transport: Bus = Bus()) {
        self.transport = transport
    }
}

struct BlueBusLine: Transportation {
    let transport: Bus
    var name = "Blue line"
    init(transport: Bus = Bus()) {
        self.transport = transport
    }
}
```

We can then type erase `Transportation` using the base and box pattern and classes, as described by [bignerdranch here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/):

```
final class AnyTransportation<_Transport: Vehicle>: Transportation {
    typealias Transport = _Transport
    private let box: _AnyTransportationBase<Transport>
    init<Concrete: Transportation>(_ concrete: Concrete) where Concrete.Transport == Transport {
        box = _AnyTransportationBox(concrete)
    }
    init(transport: Transport) { fatalError("Use type erasing init instead") }
    var transport: Transport { return box.transport }
    var name: String { return box.name }
}

final class _AnyTransportationBox<Concrete: Transportation>: _AnyTransportationBase<Concrete.Transport> {
    private let concrete: Concrete
    init(_ concrete: Concrete) { self.concrete = concrete; super.init() }
    required init(transport: Transport) { fatalError("Use type erasing init instead") }
    override var transport: Transport { return concrete.transport }
    override var name: String {return concrete.name }
}

class _AnyTransportationBase<_Transport: Vehicle> : Transportation {
    typealias Transport = _Transport
    init() { if type(of: self) == _AnyTransportationBase.self { fatalError("Use Box class") } }
    required init(transport: Transport) { fatalError("Use type erasing init instead") }
    var transport: Transport { fatalError("abstract") }
    var name: String { fatalError("abstract") }
}
```

We can then put either `RedBusLine` or `BlueBusLine` in

```
let busRides: [AnyTransportation<Bus>] = [AnyTransportation(RedBusLine()), AnyTransportation(BlueBusLine())]
busRides.forEach { print($0.name) } // prints "Red line\nBlue line"
```

In the blog post about type erasure linked to above, what I want is actually a workaround for `Homogeneous Requirement`.

Imagine we have another `Vehicle`, e.g a `Ferry` and a `FerryLine`:

```
struct Ferry: Vehicle {
    var speed: Int { return 40 }
}

struct FerryLine: Transportation {
    let transport: Ferry = Ferry()
    var name = "Ferry line"
}
```

I guess we want to type erase `Vehicle` now? Because we want an array of `AnyTransportation<AnyVehicle>`, right?

```
final class AnyVehicle: Vehicle {
    private let box: _AnyVehicleBase
    init<Concrete: Vehicle>(_ concrete: Concrete) {
        box = _AnyVehicleBox(concrete)
    }
    var speed: Int { return box.speed }
}

final class _AnyVehicleBox<Concrete: Vehicle>: _AnyVehicleBase {
    private let concrete: Concrete
    init(_ concrete: Concrete) { self.concrete = concrete; super.init() }
    override var speed: Int { return concrete.speed }
}

class _AnyVehicleBase: Vehicle {
    init() { if type(of: self) == _AnyVehicleBase.self { fatalError("Use Box class") } }
    var speed: Int { fatalError("abstract") }
}

// THIS DOES NOT WORK
let rides: [AnyTransportation<AnyVehicle>] = [AnyTransportation(AnyVehicle(RedBusLine())), AnyTransportation(AnyVehicle(FerryLine()))] // COMPILE ERROR: error: argument type 'RedBusLine' does not conform to expected type 'Vehicle'
```

Of course this does not work... because `AnyTransportation` expects passing in a type conforming to `Transportation`, but `AnyVehicle` does not conform to it of course.

But I have not been able to figure out a solution for this. Is there any?

#### Question 1: Is it possible to type erase the Simple Scenario allowing for: `[AnyTransportation<AnyVehicle>]`?

#### Question 2: If the Simple Scenario is solvable, is the original scenario also solvable?

Below follows only a more detailed explanation of what I want to achieve with the *Original Scenario*

### Original Scenario - Expanded

My original need is to put any `Transportation`, having any `Vehicle`, that in itself has any `Motor` inside the same array:

```
let transportations: [AnyTransportation<AnyVehicle<AnyMotor>>] = [BusLine(), FerryLine()] // want to put `BusLine` and `FerryLine` in same array
```

Comment: This article might help: https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/0b5188eaa825b1239389b377d8cb23c1 > Two Level Type Erasing in Swift 3
> > Recently I converted a project of mine to Swift 3
> (https://github.com/dtartaglia/XStreamSwift) and I had to deal with a
> problem that I couldn't find an answer for. This article is about the
> problem and the solution I discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to express any transportation with any vehicle with any engine, then you want 3 boxes, each talking in terms of the "previous" type-erased wrappers. You don't want generic placeholders on any of these boxes, as you want to talk in terms of fully heterogenous instances (e.g not any transportation with a *specific* `Vehicle` type, or any vehicle with a *specific* `Motor` type).

Furthermore, rather than using a class hierarchy to perform the type erasing, you can use closures instead, which allows you to capture the base instance rather than storing it directly. This allows you to remove a significant amount of the boilerplate from your original code.

For example:

```
protocol Motor {
    var power: Int { get }
}

protocol Vehicle {
    associatedtype Engine : Motor
    var engine: Engine { get }
}

protocol Transportation {
    associatedtype Transport : Vehicle
    var transport: Transport { get }
    var name: String { get set }
}

// we need the concrete AnyMotor wrapper, as Motor is not a type that conforms to Motor
// (as protocols don't conform to themselves).
struct AnyMotor : Motor {

    // we can store base directly, as Motor has no associated types.
    private let base: Motor

    // protocol requirement just forwards onto the base.
    var power: Int { return base.power }

    init(_ base: Motor) {
        self.base = base
    }
}

struct AnyVehicle : Vehicle {

    // we cannot directly store base (as Vehicle has an associated type). 
    // however we can *capture* base in a closure that returns the value of the property,
    // wrapped in its type eraser.
    private let _getEngine: () -> AnyMotor

    var engine: AnyMotor { return _getEngine() }

    init<Base : Vehicle>(_ base: Base) {
        self._getEngine = { AnyMotor(base.engine) }
    }
}

struct AnyTransportation : Transportation {

    private let _getTransport: () -> AnyVehicle
    private let _getName: () -> String
    private let _setName: (String) -> Void

    var transport: AnyVehicle { return _getTransport() }
    var name: String {
        get { return _getName() }
        set { _setName(newValue) }
    }

    init<Base : Transportation>(_ base: Base) {
        // similar pattern as above, just multiple stored closures.
        // however in this case, as we have a mutable protocol requirement,
        // we first create a mutable copy of base, then have all closures capture
        // this mutable variable.
        var base = base
        self._getTransport = { AnyVehicle(base.transport) }
        self._getName = { base.name }
        self._setName = { base.name = $0 }
    }
}

struct PetrolEngine : Motor {
    var power: Int
}

struct Ferry: Vehicle {
    var engine = PetrolEngine(power: 100)
}

struct FerryLine: Transportation {
    let transport = Ferry()
    var name = "Ferry line"
}

var anyTransportation = AnyTransportation(FerryLine())

print(anyTransportation.name) // Ferry line
print(anyTransportation.transport.engine.power) // 100

anyTransportation.name = "Foo bar ferries"
print(anyTransportation.name) // Foo bar ferries
```

Note that we still built `AnyMotor` despite `Motor` not having any associated types. This is because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878), so we cannot use `Motor` itself to satisfy the `Engine` associated type (that requires `: Motor`) – we currently have to build a concrete wrapper type for it.

Comment: THANKS ALOT for your awesome answer, it means a lot to me! Really, thanks! However, my version was very much simplified than my original problem, short version: can we typeerase *setter*s using the type erasure pattern with structs? That is why I used the class/Base/Box pattern.

Comment: @Sajjon Sure! In the initialiser, just say `var base = base`, then store, for example, a `_setName` closure that does `{ base.name = $0 }` (and then forward onto this closure in the setter of `name`). I'll update my answer to show an example.

Comment: Right! I will try to translate into my own problem domain, and will get back to you if it doesn't work. I am upvoting and accpeted your answer, thanks again!

Comment: is it possible to Type Erase an initializer e.g. `init(foo: Int)`? :O

Comment: @Sajjon The problem with attempting to add an initialiser (or static method) to one of the type erasers given above is that there's no underlying concrete type to forward the call onto, so generally there's no reasonable way to implement it. You'd need a completely separate type eraser to represent a type-erased `P.Type` metatype with the static requirements of the protocol as instance members. Although that being said, there's probably a better solution to your underlying problem, but it's hard to say for sure without seeing some more context about the concrete problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi @Hamish, as I was looking for answer to my own question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610218/how-to-type-erase-a-swift-pat-that-exposes-an-init) I came across your latest comment. If you have some extra entrypoints for me to explore a solution, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hamish's solution is definitely the correct way to do what you've asked, but when you get into this much type erasure, you need to ask yourself some questions.

Let's start at the end:

```
let transportations: [AnyTransportation<AnyVehicle<AnyMotor>>] = [BusLine(), FerryLine()] // want to put `BusLine` and `FerryLine` in same array
```

What can you possibly do with `transportations`? Seriously, what code would you write that iterated over it without doing `as?` checking? The only general method available is `name`. You couldn't really call anything else because the types would mismatch at compile time.

This is really close to the example from my [Beyond Crusty](https://www.dotconferences.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols) talk, and I think you should be looking to the same place for solutions. For example, rather than this:

```
struct RedBusLine: Transportation {
    let transport: Bus
    var name = "Red line"
    init(transport: Bus = Bus()) {
        self.transport = transport
    }
}
```

consider solutions that look like this (i.e. no protocols and all the PAT problems evaporate):

```
let redBusLine = Transportation(name: "Red line",
                                transport: Vehicle(name: "Bus", 
                                                   motor: Motor(power: 100))
```

Next, think really hard about whether you mean `Bus` to be a struct. Are two busses with the same properties the same bus?

```
let red = Bus()
let blue = Bus()
```

Are red and blue the same bus? If they're not, then this is not a value type. This is a reference type and should be a class. A lot of Swift talks push us towards protocols and shame us about classes, but the actual design of Swift encourages exactly the opposite. Make sure you're avoiding classes because these are real value types, and not just out of peer pressure. Don't use protocols just because it's Swift. I find PATs to be a tool for very specialized needs (like Collection), not a go-to solution for most problems. (Until Swift 4, even Collection was a total mess of a protocol.)